# Calling stored procedure from groovy using GString variation

Tags: sql, groovy

In groovy tutorial: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features

there is section about procedure. When I try this example:

```
The same example again but with a GString variation:

def first = 'Sam'
sql.call("{$Sql.VARCHAR = call FullName($first)}") { name ->
    assert name == 'Sam Pullara'
}
```

I got exception:

```
Chyba: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'FULLNAME' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'FULLNAME' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
```

yes that is true what exception says because I got just procedure FULLNAME what I want to call not function. Is this tutorial still actual ?

Comment: Try it with a different db. My guess is that Oracle is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a stored procedure cannot return a value and a function can return a value. This is why you get that error. You can verify using my testing stored procedure and groovy code...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_procedure
( string_in IN OUT VARCHAR2 ) IS
BEGIN
string_in := 'hi ' || string_in ;
END;

import groovy.sql.Sql

Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:dbname", username","password","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

def first="Wade"
sql.call '{call test_procedure(?)}',

    [Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(first))],
    { test ->
        println ">>" +  test  + "<<"; // >>hi Wade<<
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes

Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:dbname", "username","password","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
dept_id = 50

sql.call('{? = call FullName(?)}', [Sql.VARCHAR, 'Sam']) { name->
    println name
}
```